# Visual Studio Webform Login Page (C#) button onlick sends to a html page

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, webforms

So I'm *really* new to HTML and C#, and I'm looking to create a test website - which works for the most part.
What I'm attempting to do is create a basic login page, using webforms, that if the user is verified, it them redirects them to a different page.

So at the minute my c# "if" statement for my "submit" button looks like;

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    LoginStatus.Visible = true;
    LogoutButton.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    LoginForm.Visible = true;
}
```

Now, in my previous html pages, I simply "dragged and dropped" the item from "Solution Explorer" but when I do it this time, it copies the file location over instead.

What I would like it to do is navigate to the "zSupport.html" page I've made, if the user inputs valid login credentials.
Any ideas?

Comment: When you are new to HTML and C#, please do not use a legacy, outdated, largely unsupported platform like WebForms. Use [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) as a replacement of WebForms or use [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview).

Answer (score 0):

Upon authentication, add a line of code to simply redirect the user to your other page by calling HttpResponse.Redirect:

[HttpResponse.Redirect(String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpResponse_Redirect_System_String_System_Boolean_)